# Безопасно ли делать reboot в другую ОС?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, boot, dual-boot

Стоит dualboot windows и linux. Какие могут быть проблемы, если сделать не "вход в 1 систему -> выключение -> вход в другую ОС", а "вход в 1 систему -> reboot -> вход в другую ОС"? Эквивалентен ли reboot выключению и включению или там могут быть какие-то "оптимизации" (частичное выключение или т.п.), которые могут привести к проблемам при загрузке в несовместимую систему? В частности, безопасно ли при обновлении windows, когда она просит перезагрузиться, включить linux, поработать там, и только потом продолжить апдейт windows?

Comment: Безопасно, системы друг с другом никак не пересекаются

Comment: Если доверяете обеим системам, то безрпасно. Если не доверяете хотя бы одной, то должны считать,, что обе могут быть скомпроментированы, поскольку все данные на носителях физически доступны из любой системы